# What's the accurate adjective used for someone who is wise, open-minded, respectful and civil?

Tags: meaning-in-context, translation

In my native language (Persian/Farsi), there is a certain widly used adjective commonly referred to people who are somehow wise, respectful and civil. Lets say the adjective is **`X`**, then for instance:

> Those who throw out trash, sound their vehicle's horn very often, 
>   have medieval ideas about the rights and roles of women and ... are
>   **`not X`**.
>
> On the other hand, those who have read a lot of books, settle their disagreement in private
>   rather than yelling at each other in a public place, respect others
>   opinion and treat them with respect and ... are **`X`**.
>
> Also talks such as *"As long as people lack (noun of)**`X`** 
>   , nothing's gonna change in this country"* are very common in my country.

It's worth mentioning that `Google` translates **`X`** to **`"Cultured"`** which is probably not very accurate.

Considering my explanations, is there any proper adjective which accurately means **`X`** in English?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to translate a word if we don't know what the word in the other language is! ;) At the moment, I think that at best you'd be given thesaurus-style answers for words approximate to the English words you've listed.

Comment: Well, "cultured" might not be as cool as whatever the word in Persian is, but it would fit pretty well in your first two examples.

Comment: @nick012000 thanks, you mean I should include the word in Persian in my question?

Comment: @joiedevivre, thank you, so is it common or native-like to say "cultured people do not throw trash from car windows"?

Comment: Yes, that sounds perfectly logical and natural to me. I'm still not sure if it expresses all the wonderful things your word does, though! Honestly, though, "cultured" might be almost _too_ nice for that idea. You don't have to be very wonderful not to throw trash out the window. That's a pretty low bar.

Comment: @joiedevivre Thank you :D I think the word which is "Farhang" btw, is a mixture of being cultured, civil and educated, so I guess I can use these synonyms separately in the right context. Thanks again :)

Comment: Of course! By the way, "cultured" already definitely implies both "civil" and "educated!" I'm just not so sure it always implies "wise" or "open-minded."

Comment: @joiedevivre : Then I guess I've had my answer. If you'd like to post your comments as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as 'accepted'. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Bahman_Aries - I'm glad you got the help you sought. You might want to wait a little longer before accepting an answer, though, as a matter of practice. [Here's why](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to say Google translate is good for anything, but I think that in this case, *cultured* fits your first two examples well. It definitely implies that a person is educated, respectful, and civil:

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cultured

It probably doesn't always mean that a person is wise or open-minded, though.

In your final example, "*as long as people lack **X**, nothing's gonna change in this country*," you'd have to change "cultured" to "culture." However, this might be the one situation where you'd want to look for a word that is more specific to your meaning. Although *cultured* is typically a praiseworthy quality, it can also have a connotation that is a little bit classist. That is, it's much harder for people who are born poor to become cultured. So, in that one case, you might prefer a word like civility or respect.

Comment: The word [_sophisticated_](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sophisticated) – which is a synonym of _cultured_ – might also work in this context.

Comment: @J.R. I think _sophisticated_ has even more classist connotations than _cultured_. I also don't really associate it with the concepts of "civility" or "manners."

Comment: @joiedevivre : True, and for this reason, I'm gonna stick to "cultured" for now :)

Comment: @Bahman_Aries I do think it fits your context better! It seems like politeness may be important here, and there's pretty much no association between sophistication and manners!

Comment: @joiedevivre - Maybe not well-mannered, but perhaps overtones of better-educated. In any case, I didn't claim it was a better word, I just thought it might be a good one for interested learners to check out.

Comment: @J.R. It really is. After a quick googling I found an articles about "how to become more sophisticated" in which the word "sophisticated" was used quite close in meaning to what I had in mind. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the word **civilized** fits your intent, both in meaning and in the context in which it can be used (it fits well into X in the first two examples).

As for the noun, **culture** may be better than **civilization**.

Also, **well-mannered** is a suitable adjective and **manners** is a good fit to the X in the third example.

Comment: One context I have in mind is something like this: "to solve the traffic problems, we shouldn't merely rely on government to take action, we, as members of the society, should also try to become more X . I think here, civilized fits well, right?

Comment: I would agree. Alternatively you could use "well-mannered" here. Both would fit better than "cultured". Actually I should add it to the answer.

Comment: Great! guess these words are all good alternatives in the right context. Thanks :)

Comment: Still, I have some doubts about "manners" because lack of "x" in Persian might be even considered the root of all problems in developing countries. But "manners" seems a little too light to have such an impact.

Comment: Some words don't have exact translations, especially when they describe something very culture-specific (arguably, some cultures are not civilized...) This may be one of them.